# animation in animation doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

After reading and testing it doesn't work, animate one element while another is in animation:

```
        var wWidth = $(window).innerWidth(),
        count = $('.slide').length;

        $('body *').css('width',wWidth);
        $('.slide div').each(function(ind,el) {
            $(el).css({
                'left': (wWidth*(ind+1))
            });
        });


        function startAnimation() {
            $(".slide div.image2" ).animate({
                left: wWidth/4,
                opacity:1
            }, {
                duration: 1800,
                step: function( now, fx ){
                    $( ".slide div.image1" ).animate( {left:0,opacity:1 },1800);
                }
            });

        };
        function finishAnimation() {
            $(".slide div.image2" ).animate({left: -wWidth,opacity:0}, {
              duration: 1000,
              step: function(now, fx) {
                if (fx.state > 0.5 && fx.prop === "width") {
                   if(!$( ".slide div.image1" ).is(':animated')) // Make sure you didn't start the animation already
                     $( ".slide div.image1" ).animate({left:-wWidth,opacity:0}, 1000);
                }
              }
            })
        }
        startAnimation();
        finishAnimation();
```

The startAnimation is working perfectly, but the finishAnimation doesnt hide and move to left .image1 div

Please help

Comment: where is your html? make a fiddle please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t6BTv/1/ - as you can see the red div stays on page the green one moves away, and i need that the red one will move too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but the only reason I see that you are trying to start the animation on `image1` inside `step` is because you want it to start when the `image2` animation is halfway done. Since you have defined animation duration, this can be achieved with a simple `$.delay`:

```
function startAnimation() {
    $(".slide div.image2")
        .animate({left: wWidth / 4, opacity: 1}, 1800)
        .animate({left: -wWidth, opacity: 0}, 1000);
    $(".slide div.image1")
        .animate({left: 0,opacity: 1}, 1800)
        .delay(500)
        .animate({left: -wWidth, opacity: 0}, 1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtGyt/2/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling:

```
 startAnimation();
 finishAnimation();
```

Put `finishAnimation` in `startAnimation`'s callback function by using [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), then simply call `startAnimation()`:

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/xtGyt/1/)

```
var wWidth = $(window).innerWidth(),
count = $('.slide').length;

$('body *').css('width',wWidth);
$('.slide div').each(function(ind,el) {
    $(el).css({
     'left': (wWidth*(ind+1))
     });
});

function startAnimation() {
        $(".slide div.image2" ).animate({
        left: wWidth/4,
        opacity:1
    }, {
        duration: 1800,
        step: function( now, fx ){
            $( ".slide div.image1" ).animate( {left:0,opacity:1 },1800);
        },
         complete: finishAnimation()
        });

    };
    function finishAnimation() {
        $(".slide div.image2" ).animate({left: -wWidth,opacity:0}, {
                 duration: 1000,
                 step: function(now, fx) {
            if (fx.state > 0.5 && fx.prop === "width") {
                 if(!$( ".slide div.image1" ).is(':animated')) // Make sure you didn't start the animation already
                      $( ".slide div.image1" ).animate({left:-wWidth,opacity:0}, 1000);
                 }
              }
              });
     }
     startAnimation();
```

Comment: id doesn't work, both images needs to slide from left, one after another, and then both slide left until they disappear